# Reduce velocity to a fraction of itself over time

Tags: physics, computer-science

I have a velocty variable, and I want it to get reduced constantly over time so that every second it becomes equal to $x\%$ of it's initial value.
I can update the variable periodically, but the time between updates is subject to fluctuations (e.g.: the framrate in a videogame), how do I account for that?

I realized that computing:

$$vel = vel * 0.9 * timeDelta$$

Doesn't reduce the velocity by 10% over a second. In fact, depending on the values of $timeDelta$, the value of $vel$ after a second falls within a certain range.

Edit:
As @PhilH pointed out, $timeDelta$ should be an exponent of $0.9$ (or, in general, whatever the reduction is).
So, on every update, $vel$ should be updated like this
$$vel = vel * 0.9^{timeDelta}$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773)

Comment: Time delta needs to be an exponent of $0.9$.

Comment: @PhilH that's it! Thanks!